# Two fixed width divs, and another div with dynamic size between

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The title says everything. I want something like this:

[image]

The left box should be positioned in the left, the right one in the right. They both should have fixed widths, e.g. 200px. The middle div should take the size between. Its width is not set, but it takes the width that's remaining.

Thanks.

Comment: CSS flexbox would be the solution, except that support is still limited. You'll have to use tricks like absolute positioning the side divs, and using margins on the center div. Give it a try and update your question with the failed attempts if it doesn't work.

Comment: +1 for interesting topics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working [one](http://jsfiddle.net/N3qmH/2/). 
Use **margin: 0 auto;** will get your element centered most of the time. (Quick note: your element must have a declared width for this to work.)

The **margin: 0 auto;** rule is shorthand for 0 top and bottom margin, and automatic left and right margins. Automatic left and right margins work together to push the element into the center of its container.

The **margin: 0 auto;** setting doesn't work perfectly in every centering situation, but it works in a whole lot of them.

reference: [You Can't Float Center with CSS](http://www.codeitpretty.com/2012/05/you-cant-float-center.html)
 
**HTML**

```
<div class="leftsidebar">a</div>
<div class="rightsidebar">b</div>
<div class="content">c</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.leftsidebar 
{ 
height: 608px; 
width: 60px; 
background:red; 
float:left; } 

.rightsidebar 
{ 
background:blue; 
height: 608px; 
width: 163px; 
float:right; 
} 

.content 
{ 
width: auto; //or any width that you want
margin:0 auto;
background:yellow;
}
```

Comment: There is a possible slight problem with this solution as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/N3qmH/3/ . The solution being to add `overflow-x:hidden;` to the content class. This really comes down to what is wanted by the individual though.

Comment: good solution, but the margin:0 auto wasn't the main point here, it could be discarded .. width: auto is the one that worked and I wonder how, because I tried it before and it didn't!

Comment: the trick was to add both of the sides to the document before the middle so that when you add width:auto it will fill the remaining area. +1 for that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/GYzVS/

## Working great on onReady and onResize too.

## JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeMid();    
    $(window).resize(function() {
      resizeMid();
    });    
});  

function resizeMid(){
    var mid_width = $('#main').width() - ($('#left').width()+$('#right').width());
    $('#middle').css({'width':mid_width});
}
```

## HTML

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="left">Left</div>
    <div id="middle">Middle</div>
    <div id="right">Right</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#main {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0;
    background:red;
}
#middle {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
    margin:0;
    background:blue;
}
#right {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kenfly51/hzLMz/) just html and css, without javascript

```
<div class="container">
<div class="c1"></div>
<div class="c2"></div>
<div class="c3"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    height:500px;
    position:absolute;
    border:0px;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.c1, .c3 {
    width: 200px;
    background-color:red;
}
.c1, {
    left:0px;
}
.c3 {
    right:0px;
}
.c2 {
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
    background-color:blue;
    left:200px;
    right:200px;
}
.container {
    width:99%;
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent solution. It is better than the common CSS-only solution (like @bot's) where ypu write the left and right divs first, and then the middle div, but that method breaks accessibility with tabbing and screen readers. @MrF's solution is also better than table cells because you can control text content better (nowrap, overflows) without the cell auto-sizing out of control.

Answer (score 0):

**[updated]**

use a table, it will adjust it's own width. float style was the first that came to my mind but it doesn't adjust the element's width to fill in the gap.

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:10%;"><div id="d1"></div></td>
        <td><div id="d2"></div></td>
        <td style="width:10%;"><div id="d3"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

css:

```
#d1,#d3{
    background-color:red;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
#d2{
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}
table{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/kKzjN/1/)**

**update:**

if you don't want to use tables or excessive js calculations use this:

```
#d1,#d3{
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
    width:10%;
    height:300px;
}
#d2{
    float:left;
    background-color:blue;
    width:80%;
    height:300px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/QXTuD/)**

Comment: Is there any other solution? I don't prefer using tables.

Comment: yes if you want to waste resources and recalculate the width when the window resizes every time .. using javascript and resize event.

Comment: there is another way if you want to fix the width's to a percentage

Comment: Some guys here found some css-only ways that won't waste resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally avoid using JS and do this using CSS.
You can add a #container wrapper and then define the width to whatever you want and then use % for the left right and the middle div's

Sample CSS below:

```
<div id="container"> 
        <div id="left-column"> </div>
        <div id="middle-column"> <p>Content goes in here and dynamically stretches</p></div>
        <div id="right-column"> </div>
</div>

#container{
   float:left;
   width:1000px;
   *background-color:blue;
}
#left-column, #middle-column, #right-column{
        height:500px;
        float:left;
}
#left-column, #right-column {
    width:20%;
    background-color:red;
}

#middle-column {
    background-color:green;
    width:60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, still here goes.

This can be done using flexbox.

HTML

```
<div class="flex">
  <div class="fixed-div"></div>
  <div class="dynamic-div"></div>
  <div class="fixed-div"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex {
  display:flex;
 }

.fixed-div {
  width:30px;
  background-color:blue;
  height:200px;
 }

.dynamic-div {
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  height:200px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
 }
```

You can checkout the implementation [here](https://codepen.io/brainflayer/pen/PoRMdMG).